# How to write a LogExceptionAttribute for MVC3 Site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, logging, exception, attributes

In each action, I write:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    try
    {
        // Do something
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("Foo()", ex);
    }
    ...
}
```

I know MVC3 has the ability to "RegisterGlobalFilters" in Global.asax, so I want to write a custom LogExceptionAttribute. which will:

1. Log information of **which Action** cause **what Exception**. calling my Logger API:

   Logger.Error(string actionName, Exception ex)
2. throw the exception again. so that CustomError in web.config will show user error page.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  public class HandleErrorHmAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
        {
            public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
            {
                base.OnException(context);
                new WebRequestErrorEventMvc("An unhandled exception has occurred.", this, 103005, context.Exception).Raise();
            }
        }

        public class WebRequestErrorEventMvc : WebRequestErrorEvent
        {
            public WebRequestErrorEventMvc(string message, object eventSource, int eventCode, Exception exception) : base(message, eventSource, eventCode, exception) { }
            public WebRequestErrorEventMvc(string message, object eventSource, int eventCode, int eventDetailCode, Exception exception) : base(message, eventSource, eventCode, eventDetailCode, exception) { }
       }
```